# Imputing Missing Value

Tags: regex, pandas, nan

I am looking to filter the talentpool_subset dataframe to capture only the city and state from the location column (it currently contains strings like this, "Software Developer in London, United Kingdom"). I've tried replacing NaN values with 0, and confirmed that I've done this by subsetting the dataframe to return only NaN values, which returned an empty data frame as expected. But every time I run the final statement, I get this error: "ValueError: cannot mask with array containing NA / NaN values"
Why is this happening?

```
talentpool_subset = talentpool_df[['name', 'profile', 'location','skills']]
talentpool_subset

talentpool_subset['location'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
location = talentpool_subset['location'].isna()
talentpool_subset[location]

talentpool_subset[talentpool_subset['location'].str.contains(r'(?<=in).*')]

    name    profile     url     source  github  location    skills  tags_strong     tags_expert     is_available    description
0   Hugo L. Samayoa     DevOps Developer    https://www.toptal.com/resume/hugo-l-samayoa    toptal  NaN     DevOps Developer in Long Beach, CA, United States   {"Paradigms":["Agile Software Development","Sc...   NaN     ["Linux System Administration","VMware ESXi","...   available   "DevOps before DevOps" is a term mostly associ...
1   Stepan Yakovenko    Software Developer  https://www.toptal.com/resume/stepan-yakovenko  toptal  stiv-yakovenko  Software Developer in Novosibirsk, Novosibirsk...   {"Platforms":["Debian Linux","Windows","Linux"...   ["Linux","C++","AngularJS"]     ["Java","HTML5","CSS","JavaScript","MySQL","Hi...   available   Stepan is an experienced software developer wi...
2   Slobodan Gajic  Software Developer  https://www.toptal.com/resume/slobodan-gajic    toptal  bobangajicsm    Software Developer in Sremska Mitrovica, Vojvo...   {"Platforms":["Firebase","XAMPP"],"Storage":["...   ["Firebase","Karma"]    ["jQuery","HTML5","CSS3","Git","JavaScript","S...   available   Slobodan is a front-end developer with a Bache...
4   Jennifer Aquino     Query Optimization Developer    https://www.toptal.com/resume/jennifer-aquino   toptal  BlueCamelArt    Query Optimization Developer in West Ryde, New...   {"Paradigms":["Automation","ETL Implementation...   ["Data Warehouse","Unix","Oracle 10g","Automat...   ["SQL","SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)...   available   Jennifer has five years of professional experi...
```

Comment: Could you post few rows of the `DataFrame` so that the error can be reproduced?

Comment: Does that help @NileshIngle ?

Comment: Careful when uploading user's data to online services. I am on this list and it is being indexed by Google (and that is how I got here XD).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming here that the objective is to get location and it is not required to use a mask for location. Code below uses `.extract()` to keep only `city, state` in the `location` column.

For example: `Long Beach, CA, United States` from `DevOps Developer in Long Beach, CA, United States`.

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


# Create list using text from question
name = ['Hugo L. Samayoa','Stepan Yakovenko','Slobodan Gajic','Bruno Furtado Montes Oliveira','Jennifer Aquino']
profile = ['DevOps Developer','Software Developer','Software Developer','Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) Developer','Query Optimization Developer']
url = ['https://www.toptal.com/resume/hugo-l-samayoa','https://www.toptal.com/resume/stepan-yakovenko','https://www.toptal.com/resume/slobodan-gajic','https://www.toptal.com/resume/bruno-furtado-mo...','https://www.toptal.com/resume/jennifer-aquino']
source = ['toptal','toptal','toptal','toptal','toptal']
github = [np.nan, 'stiv-yakovenko','bobangajicsm','brunofurmon','BlueCamelArt']
location = ['DevOps Developer in Long Beach, CA, United States', 'Software Developer in Novosibirsk, Novosibirsk','Software Developer in Sremska Mitrovica, Vojvo','Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS) Developer in New York','Query Optimization Developer in West Ryde, New York']
skills = ['{"Paradigms":["Agile Software Development","Sc...', '{"Platforms":["Debian Linux","Windows","Linux"...','{"Platforms":["Firebase","XAMPP"],"Storage":["...','{"Paradigms":["Agile","CQRS","Azure DevOps"],"...','{"Paradigms":["Automation","ETL Implementation...']

# Create DataFrame using list above
talentpool_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'name':name,
    'profile':profile,
    'url':url,
    'source':source,
    'github':github,
    'location':location,
    'skills':skills
})

# Add NaN row to DataFrame
talentpool_df.loc[6,:] = np.nan

# Subset DataFrame to get columns of interest
talentpool_subset = talentpool_df[['name', 'profile', 'location','skills']]

# Use .extract() to keep only text after 'in' in the 'location' column
talentpool_subset['location'] = talentpool_subset['location'].str.extract(r'((?<=in).*)')
```

Output

```
talentpool_subset
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Nilesh! That was so helpful:)